# How to detect backspace in an Entry control when it is empty

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.Forms with Android. I have a form which has 4 Entry controls for a user to enter code. I am using TextChanged event to detect user input and automatically move focus to the next control. This part works fine, i.e. as user types a digit focus automatically jumps to the next entry. However, I need to achieve the opposite, user should be able to tap backspace button and focus should move to the previous control. The problem is that TextChanged is not triggered when entry control is empty. How can I achieve this? Is there a custom renderer I can create for android to capture text input? Maybe there is a way to use 1 entry instead but I need to make it look like distinct 4 boxes.

Comment: If it helps, the ASCII character for delete/backspace is '0x7f', so maybe you could detect that keyboard input and then write a corresponding action?

Comment: Why not using `Return` key to move focus to next Control ?Not suggesting using Text changed event to change focus, it can deal with other logic things.

Answer (score 3):

Finally,I've found a solution for this by implementing a renderer in android.

In shared code(PCL),Create a class like this

```
public class CustomEntry:Entry
{
    public delegate void BackspaceEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event BackspaceEventHandler OnBackspace;

    public CustomEntry()
    {

    }

    public void OnBackspacePressed()
    {
        if (OnBackspace != null)
        {
            OnBackspace(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

And,Then in your android project create a renderer like this:

```
 public class CustomEntryRenderer: EntryRenderer
 {
    public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == KeyEventActions.Down)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Del)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Control.Text))
                {
                    var entry = (PasswordBox)Element;
                    entry.OnBackspacePressed();
                }
            }
        }
        return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }

    protected override void 
    OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Entry1.OnBackspace += Entry1BackspaceEventHandler;

public void Entry1BackspaceEventHandler()
{
//things you want to do
}
```

Comment: Great Answer.. I dont know why People downvoted this answer. Works Like charm.. Little Modification   void Entry1BackspaceEventHandler(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {

Comment: You are a hero in 2021, thanks. It works perfectly.